# Validating fields on entry or embedding on submit with regex validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form for creating charges where some of the fields get entered into a table and some get sent to Stripe only.

One of the fields may cause confusion as it needs to be entered with a certain URL format via Regex and I want a custom message for when this field is entered incorrectly.

**Function I desire:** I preferably would like for it to be validated right away, sort of like how some website when you enter an incorrect email format, it will let you know either while you're still in the text field or once you click away from it.

**I have tried:**

```
  function validateHhMm(inputField) {
          var isValid = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:www|m)\.)?twitter\.com\/\w+\/status\/\d+(?:\/\/?)?\$/.test(inputField.value);

          if (isValid) {
              inputField.style.backgroundColor = '#bfa';
          } else {
              inputField.style.backgroundColor = '#fba';
          }

          return isValid;
      }
```

**with:**

```
<%= form_for(@order, url: listing_orders_path([@listing, @listing_tweet]), remote: true) do |form| %>

                             <% if @order.errors.any? %>
                               <ul>
                                 <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                                 <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                   <%= msg %>
                                 </div>
                                 <% end %>
                               </ul>
                             <% end %>

                               <div class="form-group">
                                 <%= form.label :name, "Who's the Shout for?" %>
                                 <%= form.text_field :name, class: "form-control", required: true %>
                               </div>

                               <div class="form-group">
                                 <%= form.label :email %>
                                 <%= form.text_field :email, class: "form-control", required: true   %>
                               </div>

                               <div class="form-group">
                                 <%= form.label :description %>
                                 <%= form.text_area :description, class: "form-control", :rows => 10, required: true    %>
                               </div>

                               <div class="form-group">
                                 <%= form.label :twitter_tag %>
                                 <%= form.text_field :twitter_tag, class: "form-control", required: true  %>
                               </div>

                               <div class="form-group">
                                 <div class="input-group">
                                   <%= form.label :twitter_link, "Twitter Link", id: "twitter" %>

                                 </div>
                                 <%= form.text_field :twitter_link, class: "form-control", required: true  %>
                               </div>

                               <script
                                 src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/">
                               </script>

                                 <div class="form-row">
                                   <label for="card-element-2">
                                     Credit or debit card
                                   </label>
                                   <div id="card-element-2" class="form-control">
                                   </div>

                                   <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                                 </div>
                                   <br>
                                   <div class="form-group">

                                 <%= form.submit, id:"button-element" %>

                               </div>

                               <span class="token"></span>
                               <% end %>
                               <% end %>


                       </div>
```

For whatever reason, I can't get notices to pop up within this controller (it's used within another controllers show page which might be causing the issue) --- so i figured i would go this route and try with javascript / jquery as i would rather have the validation in real time.

Now, another piece to the puzzle is the **stripe code:**

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_1234567890');

var elements = stripe.elements();

var style = {
  base: {
   #styling_code_here
};

var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

card.mount('#card-element-2');

card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

var form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});

  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    var form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    form.submit();
  }
```

I added the above code because maybe i should embed the validation within that?

Aside from the attempt above, I have made a few others but none seem to work aside from validating if a field is empty, this rails already has a feature for this.  I want the validation for the regex either in real time or once the field is left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 has a built in feature:

for example this will work:

```
<%= form.text_field :twitter_link, class: "form-control", required: true, pattern: '^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:www|m)\.)?twitter\.com\/\w+\/status\/\d+(?:\/\/?)?$',
                                 title: "Click the '?' for more information"  %>
```

A message will appear when the validation isn't working.

One issue i did notice is this front end validation doesn't work when the page isn't fully loaded.  If you are going to use this, i suggest using a model validation as well as i did.